# parseInt("08") (no radix) returns 8 in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, parseint, radix

I was showing my colleague why you must always specify a radix with `parseInt` and I was surprised to see that `parseInt("08")` returns `8` in both the console of Firefox and Chrome

shouldn't it be an octal and return `0`?

[image: parseInt('08') returns 8]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt  Apparently it does not default to 10, but some form of coersion is involved.

Comment: The octal interpretation has been deprecated for a very long time, and even ES5 stipulates that implementations must not do that. I doubt there are any significant number of environments that still do.

Comment: `08` is invalid in octal, so it makes little sense to parse it as such‽

Comment: @deceze back in the day you might get `NaN`  I think

Comment: They use your specific example in this section of @Taplar's hyperlink: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix

Comment: `+08` also returns 8

Comment: Also see the compatibility chart at the end. The change to parsing it as decimal happened in Chrome 23 and Firefox 21.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for old timers

Before 2011, `parseInt("08")` used to return `0` as `parseInt` would determine `08` was an octal as it started with an `0`

As @Pointy pointed out, the `radix` being octal for string starting with a `0` has been deprecated for a long time now

As the radix used in this case depends on the implementation, you should specify a radix (`parseInt("08", 10)` because there is no way to be sure whether the octal or decimal algorithm will be used

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Browser_compatibility